# how to theme a GROUP of webforms?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, webforms

i understand how to get the webform-form-[nid].tpl.php naming convention to theme one individual web form - it works great. what i really need, however, is to theme a **group** of web forms based on something like a taxonomy term. how can i get ALL web forms tagged with, say, "3-column" to use just that one form template file? otherwise i'll have a separate template file for every individual web form that i need. is that possible? i'm using the 6.x version of webform.

Comment: A neat thing about webform is that the same version number works almost exactly the same on 7.x and 6.x.  This is different than the approach taken by most Drupal modules.  So what's relevant to your question is not which version of Drupal you are running but which version of Webform (2.x, 3.x, etc.)

Comment: sorry about that. webform 6.x-2.x i believe. i know this could somehow be accomplished by forcing a template with a preprocess function, but not sure where to start with webform.